# How to convert a Date String "09-JUN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM" to date format in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date-format

I have an CSV file with Date specified as String as below format. I am not able to insert the date to Oracle Date Column as it shows "Date Format Not Recognized - Error" . Can someone help me to convert it.

### Sample Dates in CSV

```
09-JUN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM

21-MAR-16 12.00.00.000000000 AM

11-JUL-16 12.00.00.000000000 AM

26-OCT-15 12.00.00.000000000 AM

04-JAN-16 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

Comment: use to_date function

Comment: I am asking about the format to use to convert it

Answer (score 3):

Given that your strings have milliseconds, you need to convert them to `timestamp`:

```
to_timestamp( '09-JUN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM', 'nls_language=English')
```

Also, given that the months are written th the format `MON` you'd better ensure to use English language in conversion.
WHen you use the result to insert into a date column, only the date patr will be kept, and milliseconds will be lost:

```
SQL> create table tabDate (d date);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into tabDate
  2  select to_timestamp( '09-JUN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM', 'nls_language=English')
  3  from dual;

1 row created.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this

```
to_timestamp('09-JUN-2014 12.00.00.000000000 AM', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh.mi.ss.ff7 AM')
```